# QLabel text set from a function that returns a QString

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

My problem is the .cpp file.  I have had the text set in my Qlabel, but I'd like to return the text via a function since it's going to eventually change based on user input.

I've tried;

```
ui->label->setText()->myDirectory::getDirectory();
```

as well as the code below.

mainwindow.h

```
class myDirectory
{
     Qstring m_myDirectory = "/home/user/Desktop/"
public:
     getDirectory()
     {
      return m_myDirectory;
     }
 };
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
ui->setupUi(this);
myDirectory dir;
//I'd like to set the text to the QString returned by myDirectory::getDirectory
ui->label->setText(QString(myDirectory::getDirectory());
}
```

EDIT:

The ui->label->setText() line written correctly is

```
ui->label->setText(dir.getDirectory());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some mistakes in your code. I think you should follow some tutorial about C++ to know the basis.

```
class myDirectory
{
    Qstring m_myDirectory = "/home/user/Desktop/"
public:
    getDirectory()
    {
        return m_myDirectory;
    }
};
```

In a class, you need a constructor. It's also better to put attributes in the private section and access them via getters/setters. It could be nice to initialize your variable in your constructor too to respect some norm.

**myDirectory.h**

```
class myDirectory
{
public:
    myDirectory();             // constructor
    QString getDirectory();    // getter

private:
    Qstring m_myDirectory;
};
```

**myDirectory.cpp**

```
myDirectory::myDirectory()      // constructor
{
    m_myDirectory = "/home/user/Desktop/";
}
QString myDirectory::getDirectory()     // getter
{
    return m_myDirectory;
}
```

In your mainwindow:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->label->setText(QString(myDirectory::getDirectory());
}
```

You want to create a **QString** object with a **QString** argument, it will work but it's useless in your case.

When you write `myDirectory::getDirectory()`, you call the getDirectory() function of myDirectory class. Calling a function without instantiating object is allowed only with static function.

In you case, you should instantiate an object:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    myDirectory dir;
    ui->label->setText(dir.getDirectory());
}
```

Comment: @Martin , I apologize, I did instantiate an object of my class.  I asked the question incorrectly.  I will fix my code above.  Having said that, you did answer my question.

Comment: @Leiaz: Yeap, that's my new invention after a looong day work ^^ (I edited :p)